# A Haar measure is a left invariant Borel measure which is not identically zero

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A Haar measure is a Borel measure $\mu$ in a locally compact topological group $X$, such that $\mu$(U)>0 for every non empty Borel open set $U$, and $\mu(xE)$=$\mu(E)$ for every Borel set $E$.

A Borel measure is a measure $\mu$ defined on the class $S$ of all Borel sets and such that $\mu$(C)< $\infty$ for every C in $C$.

we shall denote by $C$ the class of all compact subsets of X ,by S the $\sigma$-ring generated by $C$.we shall call the sets of S the borel sets of X.

We want to show that the first property is equivalent to the assertion that $\mu$ is not identically zero.

If $\mu(U)$=0 for some non empty Borel open set $U$, and if $C$ is any compact set,then the class $\{xU\mid x \in C\}$ is an open covering of $C$.
Since $C$ is compact, there exists a finite subset $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $C$ such that $C \subset \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i U$, and the left invariance of $\mu$ implies that 
$$\mu(C)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mu(x_iU)=n\mu(U)=0.
$$ Since the vanishing on the class $C$ of all compact sets implies its vanishing on the class $S$ of all Borel sets, we obtain the desired result.

My question is:

> Why is the class $\{xU\mid x \in C\}$ an open covering of $C$?
>   And why does the vanishing on the class $C$ of all compact sets implies its vanishing on the class $S$ of all Borel sets?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: The assumption that $\mu(C)<\infty$ for all $C\in S$ is very strange--it actually implies that $X$ must be compact, rather than locally compact.

Comment: Also, what is your definition of "Borel set"?  From the fact that you are referring to "Borel open sets", I assume your definition is the $\sigma$-ring generated by compact sets rather than the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me begin by clarifying a few things about the definition.  First, I assume from your phrasing that you are defining the "Borel sets" to be the $\sigma$-ring generated by the compact subsets of $X$ (rather than the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open subsets of $X$).  Second, the definition of Haar measure should *not* say that $\mu(C)<\infty$ for all Borel sets $C$; it should only say that $\mu(C)<\infty$ for all *compact* sets $C$.  If you assume $\mu(C)<\infty$ for all Borel sets, this actually implies $X$ must be compact (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676578/finite-haar-measure-if-and-only-if-compact)).

Let me now address your questions.  For the first question, it is true that $\{xU\mid x\in C\}$ covers $C$ *if $U$ contains the identity $1\in G$*, since then $x\in xU$ for each $x\in C$.  But the $U$ we were given might not contain the identity, and in that case there is no reason to expect $\{xU\mid x\in C\}$ to cover $C$.  To fix this, just let $y\in U$ be any point, and replace $U$ with $y^{-1}U$.

For the second question, simply note that the collection of Borel sets $E$ such that $\mu(E)=0$ is a $\sigma$-ring, so if it contains all compact sets, then by definition it contains all Borel sets.

Comment: Additional note: If we define the Borel sets as usual, then vanishing on all compact sets implies vanishing on all open sets, since usually it is required that the Haar measure is **Radon**, which in particular implies $\mu (U)=\sup_{K\subset U}\mu (K) $ (with K compact) for each open U and $\mu (E)=\inf_{U\supset E}\mu (U) $ (with U open) for arbitrary Borel sets.

Comment: for the second question,in proving that the collection of Borel sets $E$ such that $\mu(E)=0$ is a $\sigma$-ring
in the part of proving that it is closed under difference
if we suppose that E is a borel set s.t. $\mu$(E)=0 and F is a borel set s.t. $\mu$(F)=0 then E-F is a borel set is ok for me but how to prove $\mu$(E-F)=0.
for the first question,it is from halmos's book "measure theory"p.252
i still have the same question and how he use also that U is open in proving that the class $\{xU\mid x \in C\}$ is an ""open"" covering of $C$.

Comment: Since $E-F\subseteq E$, $\mu(E-F)\leq \mu(E)=0$.  If $U$ is open, then $xU$ is open for any $x$ because multiplication by $x$ is a homeomorphism (it is continuous, as is its inverse, multiplication by $x^{-1}$).